# Shockwave player not working?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, chromium, adobe

These are two separate Chromium windows:

[image]

I find this very strange! The test website i am using is [this](https://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/) one, Shockwave. I have restarted all web browsers after installing via [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html) method. I am using Chromium, the problem also affects Firefox if it makes any difference.

The flash on [this](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) website works. Shockwave does not work on Firefox either although it says it is installed:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's because Ubuntu has outdated Flash versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the names, Adobe Shockwave and Adobe Flash are two different programs/plugins. Adobe Shockwave isn't available for Linux, whereas Adobe Flash is available for Linux.

You have both the NPAPI version of Flash (which all browsers except Chrome(ium) use) and the PPAPI version of Flash (which Chrome(ium) uses) installed.

Comment: I finally came to the same conclusion that Shockwave is just too old and does not exist for Linux. VM with Windows or Wine it will have to be.